# Is it possible to have kernel newer than 5.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Nvidia driver active?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, kernel, gpu-driver

I see that only kernel version 5.4 is available for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS by HWE package named [`linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04).

It is known that Mainline kernels will not work with Nvidia drivers from Ubuntu repository.

How can I obtain newer kernel version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible by downloading kernel sources from newer Ubuntu release - say Ubuntu 21.10 (impish) using relevant Docker container and then compile kernel on target 18.04 LTS system with small modifications as follows:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/impish-kernel
```

Then place below code into `compile-impish-kernel.sh` script inside `~/Downloads/impish-kernel` directory by using any text-editor:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# prepare download script
cat << EOF > script.sh
set -x

sed -i "s/# deb-src/deb-src/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y dpkg-dev
cd && apt-get source linux
chown -R 1000:1000 linux* 
EOF

# run script inside container
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/root -it ubuntu:impish sh /root/script.sh

cd linux-5.13.0
echo 9 > debian/compat
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules clean

sed -i "s/^CONFIG_KASAN/#CONFIG_KASAN/" debian.master/config/annotations
sed -i "s/^CONFIG_KCSAN/#CONFIG_KCSAN/" debian.master/config/annotations
LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch

ls ../linux-headers-5.13*.deb ../linux-image-unsigned-5.13*.deb ../linux-modules-*.deb
```

Run the script by

```
chmod +x compile-impish-kernel.sh
./compile-impish-kernel.sh
```

and finally install 5.13 kernel packages by

```
sudo apt-get install ./linux-headers-5.13*.deb ./linux-image-unsigned-5.13*.deb ./linux-modules-*.deb
```

As the result the 5.13 kernel will be installed. Nvidia driver will operate normally.